Google Sheets Script only runs once, why?
I have a google script function that gets data from a website. It does this successfully on the first call (triggered by a button), but nothing happens on subsequent calls--the page does not redraw.
If I manually edit the script (in the last line of the script, below) to change back and forth from csv to web after each run, then it works. What am I missing?
function refresh() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet4"); 
sheet.getRange(1,2).setFormula('importdata("https://ottoneu.fangraphs.com
    /mockdraftresultsexport/93?csv=1")');
}


If a formula's arguments don't change, they are not refreshed. IMPORTDATA automatically refreshes every hour or so.  You can however add a random number to the url to force a refresh(assuming the server doesn't mind):
const url="...";//url without query parameters(url before the "?")
const formula = `importdata("${url}?csv=1&rand=${Math.random()}")`
sheet.getRange(1,2).setFormula(formula)

Also see Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet

Brilliant! Thanks very much.

@chris See how to accept
